# How to set minimum window size using WinApi

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

now I'm creating app with WinApi and I need to have GUI window which has to be at least 300x300 size, how can I set this low boundry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In your window procedure:

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
{
    LPMINMAXINFO lpMMI = (LPMINMAXINFO)lParam;
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = 300;
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = 300;
}
```

Read more about `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)